# How to delete LAST blank lines and add one in the end of file?

Tags: vim, neovim

I should follow python style guide. And i want to delete all blank lines in the end of file but one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move the cursor to last line:

   ```
   G
   ```
2. Vim considers a series of blank lines as a "paragraph", which may seem odd but works in our favour, here, because we can change the current paragraph:

   ```
   cip
   ```

   and immediately go back to normal mode:

   ```
   <Esc>
   ```

Demo:

[image: demo]

---

But, as far as I can tell, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), doesn't mandate that and I suspect that the last blank line you want to keep may be a misunderstanding.

Comment: I want to automate it on save

Comment: That wasn't part of the question.

Comment: and you don't want to answer... OKAY!

Comment: This answer fits your question as you asked it. Ask another question instead of sneakily moving the goal post.